# Не загружается windows после удаления разделов с Linux

Tags: linux, windows, grub

На ноутбуке имелись Windows и Linux Mint. Понадобилось удалить Linux.

Зашел в управление разделами в windows, и просто удалил два раздела (99 ГБ и 230 МБ). Перезагружаю компьютер. Появляется сообщение:

> error: no such partition.
>   Entering rescue mode...
>
> grub rescue>

В интернете рекомендуют загрузить диск с Windows 7, но у меня нет такого диска, так как винда стояла изначально на ноутбуке.

Comment: Всё правильно сказали. Ищите диск с Windows соответствующей версии и с него восстанавливайте загрузчик. Можно вместо диска попробовать загрузиться с флешки.

Comment: Пиратская версия пойдет ?

Comment: Подойдёт и пиратка.

Answer (score 5):

фактически вам надо скопировать стандартный *mbr* в первый сектор вашего винчестера.

это можно сделать, например, с помощью практически любого live-cd/dvd/usb с операционной системой *gnu/linux*.

сам файл размером 440 байт, скорее всего, имеется прямо на live-cd/dvd/usb.

1. после загрузки с этого носителя проверьте наличие:

   ```
   $ find /usr -name mbr.bin -ls
   682571 4 -rw-r--r-- 1 root root    440 Dec 10  2012 /usr/lib/syslinux/mbr.bin
   ```

   приведён пример вывода, из которого видно, что файл находится по адресу `/usr/lib/syslinux/mbr.bin` и размер его как раз 440 байт.

   если файл не обнаружите, но доступен интернет, то можно скачать этот файл, например, с яндексовского зеркала:

   ```
   $ wget http://mirror.yandex.ru/mirrors/magos/netlive/2014red/boot/syslinux/mbr.bin
   ```

   этой командой он будет сохранён в текущий каталог под именем `mbr.bin`.
2. следующий шаг — надо узнать имя вашего винчестера.

   это можно сделать, например, командой:

   ```
   $ sudo fdisk -l | grep ^Disk
   Disk /dev/sda: 1000.2 GB, 1000204886016 bytes
   ...
   ```

   приведён пример вывода. если у вас подключено несколько винчестеров, то можно идентифицировать нужный по размеру (или, в крайнем случае, просто физически отключить все, кроме «основного»). ключевая строка (в данном случае) — `/dev/sda`. это и есть имя вашего винчестера.

---

вся необходимая информация собрана.

а теперь «волшебная» команда копирования того самого 440-байтного файла в первый сектор винчестера:

```
$ sudo dd if=файл of=диск
```

вместо `файл` укажите путь к найденному/скачанному на первом шаге файлу. это будет либо `/usr/lib/syslinux/mbr.bin` (из примера), либо просто `mbr.bin`, если вы его скачали/скопировали в текущий каталог.

вместо `диск` укажите имя, полученное на втором шаге.

в итоге должна получиться такая, например, команда:

```
$ sudo dd if=/usr/lib/syslinux/mbr.bin of=/dev/sda
0+1 records in
0+1 records out
440 bytes (440 B) copied, 0.0146916 s, 29.9 kB/s
```

приведён пример её вывода, из которого видно, что скопировалось ровно 440 байт.

---

инструкция на [английском](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RestoreUbuntu/XP/Vista/7Bootloader#How_to_partially_fix_the_Windows_bootloader_using_an_Ubuntu_CD)